# Perl last pattern patch variable

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

I am relatively novice to perl, and with my recent learning i ended up with some script and stumbled upon this regex

$+ which says 
the last bracket matched by the last search pattern. This is useful if you don't know which of a set of alternative patterns matched. For example:
    `/Version: (.*)|Revision: (.*)/` && `($rev = $+)`;

Sounds interesting but I could not understand what it actually does, can some one please help me understand its usage,

I also found some examples which state as below,

"`$<digit>` Regexp parenthetical capture holders."

Comment: Not sure, but `$+` might be the group number. In this case if ($+ == 2) { then matched refision }. I could be wrong about this. It sounds like its the named capture group hash though. i.e. $+{name}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$<digit>` holds the capture buffer info.

Regex -

```
   Version:\ 
   ( .* )            # (1)
|  
   Revision:\ 
   ( .* )            # (2)
```

Code -

```
if ( $str =~ /Version: (.*)|Revision: (.*)/ )
{
    if ( defined $1 ) {
        $ver = $1;
    }
    elsif ( defined $2 ) {
        $rev = $2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Regexes can have capture groups, which after a successful match contain the matched substring for that part of the pattern:

```
/Version: (.*)|Revision: (.*)/
#         $1             $2
```

These are enumerated left to right as `$1`, `$2`, …. Sometimes, we may want to access the last successful capture. E.g:

```
"Version: v123"  → "v123"
"Revision: v678" → "v678"
```

So we either need `$1` or `$2`, they will not be filled at the same time. We could do:

```
/Version: (.*)|Revision: (.*)/ and $rev = ($1 // $2)
```

which uses the `//` defined-or operator. Or we could use `$+` to refer whatever capture succeeded most recently. You can think of it a bit as `$-1`: the last capture group (except that it's not the last in the source code, but the most recent in time).

In this simple example, using `$+` might make sense, but I've never actually used it. Better workarounds include:

- Using named captures, which are accessible via the `%+` hash:

  ```
  /Version: (?<rev>.*)|Revision: (?<rev>.*)/ and $rev = $+{rev}
  ```
- Resetting the numbering with the `(?| ... | ... )` construct. This breaks the normal numbering of capture groups from left to right, and instead numbers each alternative independently:

  ```
  /(?|Version: (.*)|Revision: (.*))/ and $rev = $1
  #            $1             $1
  ```

Comment: named captures is what i think i am looking at, we have few lines of code which look similar,                                           $item =~ /(?<itemName>.*)\.tst/; // looks like captures what am comparing in <itemName>
if($c_attr_val eq $+{itemName}) { and i used the last match here to compare. hopefully am making sense